# Reset/Empty fields after submit form with ajax without refresh

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a form and I want the insert and processing of the form on submit to happen without refreshing the page and for this I am using ajax however , the form is submitter  as I expected however form is not resetting to be empty after this

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#contact-form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from submitting normally
        
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();
        
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'insert.php',
          data: {name: name, email: email, message: message},
          success: function(data){
            alert('Form submitted successfully!');
          },
          error: function(data){
            alert('An error occurred while submitting the form.');
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <hr>
  <h2 id="title">Contact Us</h2><br>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 mb-5 mb-lg-0">

        <p class="mb-0" style="color: gold;"><strong>Phone:</strong></p>
        <p class="mb-0"><?php echo $rowsite["mainphone"];?></p>
        <br>
        <p class="mb-0" style="color: gold;"><strong>Email:</strong></p>
        <p class="mb-0"><?php echo $rowsite["mainemail"];?></p>
        <br>
        <p class="mb-0" style="color: gold;"><strong>Address:</strong></p>
        <p class="mb-0"><?php echo $rowsite["mainaddress"];?></p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form id="contact-form" action="insert.php" method="POST" role="form" autocomplete="off">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" style="color:gold;">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" style="color:gold;">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message" style="color:gold;">Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="5" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn" style="background-color:gold; color:white">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the insert.php file is this

```html
<?php
// Check if the form was submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    
    include "connect.php";

    // Get the form data
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    // Prepare and execute the SQL INSERT statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO contacts (name, email, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $email, $message);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Check if the insert was successful and show an alert message
    if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
        echo "<script>alert('Your message was successfully submitted!');</script>";
        header("Refresh:0"); // Reload the page to clear the form fields
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Sorry, an error occurred while submitting your message. Please try again later.');</script>";
    }

    // Close the statement
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

What could I be getting wrong? the code is working fine inserting all the info captured into thedatabase and  giving out the alertas I wanted. My issue is that I do not want the page to refresh but then also I want the fields to reset after sucesfull inserting of the data

Comment: Put `$("#contact-form").trigger("reset");` at the top of the success block in ajax return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/*

- Firstly
- if you got success response then execute this
- */

$('#contact-form').trigger("reset");

// Secondly you can use
$('.form-control').val("");